# Replace double backslash in Dart

Tags: dart, flutter

I have this escaped string:

> \u0414\u043B\u044F \u043F\u0440\u043E\u0434\u0430\u0436\u0438
>   \u043D\u0435\u0434\u0432\u0438\u0436\u0438\u043C\u043E\u0441\u0442\u0438

If I do:

```
print('\u0414\u043B\u044F \u043F\u0440\u043E\u0434\u0430\u0436\u0438 \u043D\u0435\u0434\u0432\u0438\u0436\u0438\u043C\u043E\u0441\u0442\u0438');
```

Console will show me:

```
Для продажи недвижимости
```

But if I get escaped 2 times string from the server:

> \\u0414\\u043B\\u044F
>   \\u043F\\u0440\\u043E\\u0434\\u0430\\u0436\\u0438
>   \\u043D\\u0435\\u0434\\u0432\\u0438\\u0436\\u0438\\u043C\\u043E\\u0441\\u0442\\u0438

And do some replace job:

```
var result = string.replaceAll(new RegExp(r'\\'), r'\');
```

Compiler will not decode those characters and will show same escaped string:

```
print(result);
```

Console:

> \u0414\u043B\u044F \u043F\u0440\u043E\u0434\u0430\u0436\u0438
>   \u043D\u0435\u0434\u0432\u0438\u0436\u0438\u043C\u043E\u0441\u0442\u0438

How I can remove those redunant slashes?

Comment: Have you tried with: `string.replaceAll(new RegExp(r'\\\\'), '\');` ?

Comment: It will be error, second argument escapes '

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In string literals in Dart source files, `\u0414` is a literal representing a unicode code point, whereas in the case of data returned from the server, you're just getting back a string containing backslashes, `u`s, and digits that *looks* like a bunch of unicode code point literals.

The ideal fix is to have your server return the UTF-8 string you'd like to display rather than a string that uses Dart's string literal syntax that you need to parse. Writing a proper parser for such strings is fairly involved. You can take a look at [unescapeCodeUnits](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/9a69a5c1ee5ebd90f7e4c96cef690406b79d76ea/pkg/front_end/lib/src/fasta/quote.dart#L177) in the Dart  SDK for an example.

A very inefficient (not to mention entirely hacky and unsafe for real-world use) means of decoding this particular string would be to extract the string representations of the unicode codepoints with a `RegExp` parse the hex to an int, then use `String.fromCharCode()`.

Note: the following code is *absolutely not safe for production use* and doesn't match other valid Dart code point literals such as `\u{1f601}`, or reject entirely invalid literals such as `\uffffffffff`.

```
// Match \u0123 substrings (note this will match invalid codepoints such as \u123456789).
final RegExp r = RegExp(r'\\\\u([0-9a-fA-F]+)');

// Sample string to parse.
final String source = r'\\u0414\\u043B\\u044F \\u043F\\u0440\\u043E\\u0434\\u0430\\u0436\\u0438 \\u043D\\u0435\\u0434\\u0432\\u0438\\u0436\\u0438\\u043C\\u043E\\u0441\\u0442\\u0438';

// Replace each \u0123 with the decoded codepoint.
final String decoded = source.replaceAllMapped(r, (Match m) {
  // Extract the parenthesised hex string. '\\u0123' -> '123'.
  final String hexString = m.group(1);

  // Parse the hex string to an int.
  final int codepoint = int.parse(hexString, radix: 16);

  // Convert codepoint to string.
  return String.fromCharCode(codepoint);
});
```

Comment: Alternatively, since the format seems to fit, it's also possible to use `jsonDecode` to convert the `\u0014` to a characters. It has to be inside a JSON string literal, so maybe: `var realString = jsonDecode('"${badString.replaceAll(r"\\", r"\")}"');`.

Comment: Code from @cbracken works fine, thanks. Just one little question - can you provide some link about groups in the Match?

Comment: For details on match groups, see the API docs for [Match](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-core/Match-class.html). I'd note again that the above code is not production-safe or at all performant. As @lrn notes, using `jsonDecode`, which hadn't crossed my mind is probably a much better idea both from the point of view of performance and correctness.